# Running Azure Functions on demand locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microservices

We have a platform backed by a bunch of serverless Azure Functions, and that number is growing by the day.

To run the platform locally we have all these functions running in local docker containers which works, but it's quickly becoming resource intensive.

In an ideal world, we'd be able to have our own local serverless engine, where the functions scale to 0 and only come up when they're needed (in response to a request being sent to them). I do not believe such software exists?

I don't have a solution to this problem yet, an alternative is giving every engineer their own 'local' instance of every function in the cloud, but this may get pricey even with the generous price plans. How have others approached this problem?

Comment: https://keda.sh/ could help you

Answer (score -1):

For local testing user Functions Core Tools
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#start